# scipy osx 10.9 can't load gfortran library

Tags: python, macos, scipy, fortran, homebrew

I have tried installing scipy with pip and brew and both installs give this error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.3/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.so
  Reason: image not found
```

looking for the offending library shows a version for a different archetecture available:

```
administrators-iMac-3:sourcefind_python bill$ locate libgfortran.3.dylib
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.3.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/i386/libgfortran.3.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/libgfortran.3.dylib
```

I did try to place a symlink at /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.3/libgfortran.3.dylib to point to usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/libgfortran.3.dylib but this gave me an error 'wrong architecture'

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn is looking for an old version of the fortran library. You should reinstall scikit-learn.

Comment: I have same problem, and reinstalling scikit-lear doesn't help.

Comment: Can you share a gist with the exact error you're seeing? When doy you see it? How are you installing scikit-learn? You may also need to rebuild numpy and scipy (probably in that order) if the location of your libgfortran.3.dylib changed.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was numpy, solved by reinstalling all (numpy, scipy and scikit)

Comment: I just updated all the things, and it didn't make any difference. I'm not actually using scikit, I'm seeing this error with statsmodels. My libgfortran.2.dylib and and libgfortran.3.dylib live in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework and in /usr/local/lib/x86_64/ but for some reason it's not getting loaded into my virtualenv. Maybe an anaconda problem?

Comment: switched to a different virtualenv and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall numpy and scipy.